# How to use NSManaged object class using NSObject class

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsobject

I have `NSObject`  class name TrackInfo which contains tracks info like name , artist name,thumb image etc.

I use this class as downloading data and save information to that class after parsing data. 
Now I have another tab in which, I have to show some data. This is same kind of data like trackInfo. But when app is in OFFLINE, I have to make `NSManagedObject`. It is same as `trackinfo`.

Can I use `NSObject` class instead of `NSManagedObject` or Vice-Versa ?

What I basically wants to do is, I have to display track info from one class either Trackinfo (`NSObject` class) or `NSManagedObjectClass` which is used to save data when app is in offline.

Comment: have you checked raywenderlich's tutorial for core data?

Comment: Yes i took a look about that , what is my main concern is that can we use NSmanagedObject class as we are using NSObject class ?

Comment: you can use it like any other object but you cannot init it like any other nsobject because all the information regarding that is kept in your managedObjectContext. so instead of that they work similar.

Comment: SO i have to initialize object as below 

'NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"trackInfo" inManagedObjectContext:myContext];
id object = [[trackInfo alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];'

And after that i can use as like normal NSObject right ?

Comment: yep pretty much :)  since you put nil into "insertManagedObjectContext:nil" what ever the changes you make into the object will not get affected on CoreData db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can. How? You can find a useful discussion [Organising Core Data for iOS](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/06/organising-core-data-for-ios.html).

The long answer can be grabbed within the documentation.

> `NSManagedObject` is a generic class that implements all the basic
>   behavior required of a Core Data model object. It is not possible to
>   use instances of direct subclasses of `NSObject` (or any other class not
>   inheriting from `NSManagedObject`) with a managed object context. You
>   may create custom subclasses of `NSManagedObject`, although this is not
>   always required. If no custom logic is needed, a complete object graph
>   can be formed with `NSManagedObject` instances.
>
> A managed object is associated with an entity description (an instance
>   of `NSEntityDescription`) that provides metadata about the object
>   (including the name of the entity that the object represents and the
>   names of its attributes and relationships) and with a managed object
>   context that tracks changes to the object graph. It is important that
>   a managed object is properly configured for use with Core Data. If you
>   instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated
>   initializer (`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`).

About your question, it depends on what you need to achieve. If your goal is to perform a sync mechanism between your device and the server, you should set up 1) a model with a `TrackInfo` entity 2) a Core Data stack that relies on a persistent store like SQLite. Then you should modify `TrackInfo` to take into account modifications to that entity. For example, a `dirty` flag property (`0` or `1`) or a `timestamp`. When you do a modification on your `TrackInfo` you update that property. When the connection is restored you need to query against that property and sync with the server. If you choose the `timestamp`, the server should say what is the latest timestamp to query against.

Comment: YEs it is not a bad idea to set flag 1 or 0 as i said my main concern is about how can i use NSmanagedObject class as NSObject , and probable answer is NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"trackInfo" inManagedObjectContext:myContext]; id object = [[trackInfo alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];' so it will not affect that Database

Comment: A context is a sort of container. If you don't save it, no objects will be stored in the persistent store...the possible answer you have won't work. @DkKumar